Holomorphic sections of line bundles over ruled surfaces $\mathbb {CP}^1\times \Sigma_g$
Let $\Sigma$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g$, and consider the ruled surface $X = \mathbb P^1 \times \Sigma$.
Consider an holomorphic line bundle $\mathcal L \to X$ with
$$P.D.(c_1(\mathcal L )) = n [\mathbb P^1] + m [\Sigma]$$
with $n>0$ and $m< 0$.

Can we conclude that $H^0(X; L) = 0$ i.e. $L$ has no holomorphic sections?


Is there a well known  sufficient criterion to prove that $H^0(X; L) = 0$ depending on $n$ and $m$?


I think I might have found a solution in Beauville's book ("useful Remark III.5 pg. 26).
Prop if $m<0$ or $n<0$ then $H^0(X;\mathcal L) = 0$.
Proof: suppose that $\mathcal L$ has an holomorphic section, then this induces an effective divisor $D$.
Now, in $X$ we have two obvious effective and irreducible divisors, namely $C_1 = \mathbb P^1\times \{pt\}$ and $C_2 = \{pt\}\times \Sigma$ which satisfy $C_i^2 = 0$.
Now, recall that $D$ is effective and write $D = D' + a_1 C_1 + a_2 C_2$ where $D'$ is an (effective) divisor that does not contain $C_i$ and $a_i \geq 0$. Then $$D\cdot C_1  = (D'+ a_2 C_2)\cdot C_1 + a_1 C_1^2 \geq 0 $$  because $C_1^2 \geq 0$ and $(D'+ a_2 C_2)$ is effective.
On the other hand $D\cdot C_1 = m$ since in homology $[D] = n [C_1] + m [C_2]$ and $C_1\cdot C_2 = 1$.
This implies that $m \geq 0$. The same argument with $C_2$ in place of $C_1$ gives that $n\geq 0$.
